# How to block http calls, and only allow https calls in Bluemix

Tags: http, ssl, https, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am working a Java project which is deployed in Bluemix. I want to block all http calls (which are coming from a iOS mobile application in my usecase) and only allow https calls.

How can this be configured and enforced in Bluemix?

Comment: Close the HTTP port, or don't start the connector on it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to block http calls. You may want to consider handle it in your application code to route all HTTP traffic switch to HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to address this problem described on [IBM's developer works page](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/16016/how-do-i-enforce-ssl-for-my-bluemix-application.html).

Quoting from the accepted answer there:

> The Bluemix proxy server terminates the SSL and so all traffic will
>   look like HTTP to your app. However, the proxy also adds a special
>   HTTP header named $WSSC with a value of either http or https. Simply
>   check this header and, if the value is set to http, then redirect to
>   the https version of your page.
>
> UPDATE: The X-Forwarded-Proto header is now set as well.

There is also another answer there that describes how to do it via server.xml rather than application logic if you're pushing a full package that includes a custom server.xml (or are willing to).